Monitoring containerd with cAdvisor, outside of Kubernetes
I'm running a number of containers using containerd directly, spun up with the assistance of nerdctl. For various reasons, docker and podman does not suit our current usecase. Also, this is NOT a Kubernetes environment.
I was hoping to gather basic container metrics via cAdvisor, spun up as a container itself, but I am unable to get it to work.
cAdvisor itself appears to work as intended with regards to host metrics, but it does not list any of my containers in the UI, nor as part of the Prometheus metrics, despite outputiing "Registration of the systemd container factory successfully" as part of the log output, and https://github.com/google/cadvisor/blob/master/container/containerd/factory.go sees to imply that there is containerd support.
I'm using 0.49.1, and supplying the following config to the container (in part)
volumes:
  - type: bind
    source: /
    target: /rootfs
  - type: bind
    source: /var/run
    target: /var/run
  - type: bind
    source: /run
    target: /run
  - type: bind
    source: /sys
    target: /sys
command:
  - '--containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock'
  - '--containerd-namespace=default'

Regarding the namespace, and socket, ctr --address=/run/containerd/containerd.sock --namespace=default containers ls shows the presence of the containers I'm targetting, so they are present and accounted for.
Has anyone gotten something like this to work, or know conclusively that I'm barking up the wrong tree?
